# Making an interactive plot in Julia in Colab

Tags: julia, slider, google-colaboratory, interactive, makie.jl

I am trying to run Julia v1.7.3 in google colab, following the [set-up instructions from this notebook.](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_for_Pythonistas.ipynb)

It mostly runs well, but I'm having a ton of trouble getting interactive plots to work. A lot of people seem to have this difficulty as well, as there are lots of different pages online.

The most promising lead I've found is this [tutorial from Makie about how to use sliders.](https://makie.juliaplots.org/v0.15.1/examples/layoutables/slider/)

They include the following demo code:

```
using GLMakie

fig = Figure()

ax = Axis(fig[1, 1])

lsgrid = labelslidergrid!(
    fig,
    ["Voltage", "Current", "Resistance"],
    [0:0.1:10, 0:0.1:20, 0:0.1:30];
    formats = [x -> "$(round(x, digits = 1))$s" for s in ["V", "A", "Ω"]],
    width = 350,
    tellheight = false)

fig[1, 2] = lsgrid.layout

sliderobservables = [s.value for s in lsgrid.sliders]
bars = lift(sliderobservables...) do slvalues...
    [slvalues...]
end

barplot!(ax, bars, color = [:yellow, :orange, :red])
ylims!(ax, 0, 30)

set_close_to!(lsgrid.sliders[1], 5.3)
set_close_to!(lsgrid.sliders[2], 10.2)
set_close_to!(lsgrid.sliders[3], 15.9)

fig
```

However, when I run this demo code, I get a static image, with the sliders frozen in place!

Does anyone know what I could do to make the sliders actually move in google colab?

Comment: You should use WGLMakie, which is the Web-based backend.  GLMakie will only display a PNG in Jupyter notebooks since it is meant for desktop use.